# Changing how gradle determine that a version is higher than another

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I try to described dependency of a project but i have a little probleme with version dependency.

I have a dependency on "A" version 1.0.0 with depends on "B" version 3.4.20
I have a dependency on "B" version 3.4.20-P10-XXX

When gradle resolve dependency, my project depends on "B" version 3.4.20

How i can tell him that "B" in 3.4.20-P10-XXX is more recent than 3.4.20 ?

I try with resolutionStrategy.force 'xxx:B:3.4.20-P10-XXX' but it's not that i want.

All my version come from a BOM so, i think it's not a good choice to have the version hard code.

```
dependencies {
implementation platform('xxx:x-parent:5.0.0')

implementation 'xxx:B'
implementation 'xxx:A'}
```

Actually :
my project depends on B with version 3.4.20 (which is declaring in the pom of A)

Expected :
my project depends on B with version 3.4.20-PXX-XXX (which is declaring in my pom xxx:x-parent:5.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Used enforcedPlatform instead of platform.

see [enter link description here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import)